# Wortstellung bei Konjunktiv II Perfekt und "lassen"

Tags: word-order

Ist die Wortfolge richtig?

> Sie hätten mir einen längeren Text zukommen lassen sollen.

Und welche Regel gilt es hierbei zu beachten?

Comment: Ja, ist sie. Versuche einmal, den Satz in seine Bestandteile zu zerlegen: "Sie hätten ... sollen", "zukommen lassen",... - dann bekommst du ein Gefühl für die Struktur.

Comment: Da sind zwei Modalverben, *lassen* und *sollen*, aber *zukommen lassen* ist ein fester Begriff mit der Bedeutung *schicken*.

Comment: Unabhängig von der Reihenfolge ist auch der [Ersatzinfinitiv](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Ersatzinfinitiv-35882) wichtig ("hätten ... sollen" statt "hätten ... gesollt").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mir ist nicht klar, was für eine Regel du genau suchst. Aber hier sind ein paar Sätze, die allesamt wohlgefort sind und die dir also helfen können, die Regelhaftigkeit des Satzbaus zu erspüren:

> Sie sollten weniger Spaghetti essen!
>
> Sie hätten weniger Spaghetti essen sollen!
>
> Sie sollten sich beklagen!
>
> Sie hätten sich beklagen sollen!
>
> Sie dürfen sich nicht beklagen!
>
> Sie hätten sich nicht beklagen dürfen!
>
> Sie hätten sich nicht beim Koch über die Suppe beklagen dürfen!
>
> Sie hätten sich nicht beim Koch über die in die Suppe gefallene Fliege beklagen dürfen!
>
> Sie können gerne Platz nehmen!
>
> Sie hätten gerne Platz nehmen können!
>
> Sie sollten Ihre Tochter ins Kino gehen lassen!
>
> Sie hätten Ihre Tochter ins Kino gehen lassen sollen!
>
> Sie wollen Kaffee trinken?
>
> Sie hätten nicht kaffeetrinken wollen sollen!

Na gut, das letzte Beispiel ist ein bisschen überdreht. Man müsste sich sehr winden, eine Alltagssituation zu finden, wo es passen würde. Aber satzbautechnisch ist es schon korrekt. Vielleicht funktioniert es eher in so einem Kontext:

> Sie hätten nicht alles auf einmal machen wollen sollen!